# Does enable "Performance Insights" on Aurora MySQL will make any downtime?

Tags: amazon-aurora

I want to enable the new "Performance Insights" on active RDS.
Can I do that without expecting any downtime?

Thanks

Comment: Is there anything else you'd like as part of this post?

Answer (score 2):

Performance Insights does need you to mention a scheduling rule for modifications [1], which does indicate that it *may* need to restart the database for changes to take effect.

> For Scheduling of Modifications, choose one of the following:
>
> Apply during the next scheduled maintenance window – Wait to apply the Performance Insights modification until the next maintenance window.
>
> Apply immediately – Apply the Performance Insights modification as soon as possible.

However, it does appear to be an instance level setting, which means that if you have a multi instance aurora cluster, then you can modify one instance at a time, and failovers should prevent you from having any downtime.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PerfInsights.Enabling.html

Answer (score 2):

At the top it of the article it states "Enabling and disabling Performance Insights doesn't cause downtime, a reboot, or a failover."

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PerfInsights.Enabling.html